# Convert SQL query to LINQ query but only select specific values to return

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

I have myself a SQL query

```
SELECT follow_up_date, MAX(last_contact_date) AS last_contact_date
FROM db_accounts_last_contacts p
GROUP BY p.account_id
```

I have tried

```
var queryTest = context.db_accounts_last_contacts.SqlQuery(@"SELECT follow_up_date, MAX(last_contact_date) AS last_contact_date
FROM db_accounts_last_contacts p
GROUP BY p.account_id");
```

but I get this error.

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'dbModel.db_accounts_last_contacts'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

I don't want to pull out all of the information as this table maybe updated later down the line, I would just like to pull out these two columns

Comment: Does that SQL query even work?  Don't you need to have follow_up_date in the group by clause since it isn't in an aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the DB table withing the table itself.
and you are missing the "AS" before the p variable.
Try the following :

```
    var queryTest = context.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SELECT follow_up_date, MAX(last_contact_date) AS ast_contact_date
                                       FROM db_accounts_last_contacts AS p
                                       GROUP BY p.account_id, follow_up_date, ast_contact_date ");
```

let me know how it goes.

P.S.
I really recommend using EntityFramework as it converts your viewing point from an SQL'ish one into a C# pov. which is usually easier to understand.

Comment: I have created myself a view however entity framework is now complaining about "there isn't a primary key" how on earth do you set a primary key in a view here is my view    "select `p`.`account_id` AS `account_id`,`p`.`follow_up_date` AS `follow_up_date`,max(`p`.`last_contact_date`) AS `last_contact_date`,`p`.`id` AS `id` from `communique`.`communique_accounts_last_contacts` `p` group by `p`.`account_id`" Also you can't call SqlQuery on context

Comment: 1st, as @juharr said in the Comment to you question, first you must have the follow_up_date in the Group By clause. Any element in SELECT must be Grouped by. 2nd, its a bad habit to not set a primary key in a table. 3rd, in order to force entity framework to use a column as a primary key, use ISNULL.

Comment: Well I have fixed my problem using a view, the above did work so I will tick it however the reason I am using a view is, I haven't used views before so it feels nice :)